# Gradle project refresh failed in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I am trying to create a Gradle project in IntelliJ IDEA version 2016.3.4. I've installed Gradle 2.14.1, and I have Java SE 1.8.0_101 as well. I originally downloaded Gradle 3.3, but the IDEA suggested I download 2.14.1. The problem I am still running into is that I am receiving this error message:

> Error:org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.ShortTypeHandling PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle, 163.12024.16]

A `src` folder is also not being generated. I have attached a photo below of some of the settings I picked when I created the project. Is there an easy solution to fix this? Most of the other questions I found dealt with AndroidStudio. I am also doing this on a Mac. Thank you!
[image: IntelliJ IDEA project settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be worth to check if you have any proxy settings issue preventing you from connecting to the internet.

goto project settings, type proxy and search ,click Auto-detect proxy settings.

This worked for me,it could be other issues in your case but rule out this issue first please